# Run Command Prompt Commands can't run commands inside " "

Tags: c#, windows, command, regedit

i'm trying to run windows commands with this c# code:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("/C @shift /0");
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("/C @echo off");
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("/C color 04");
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("/C title Loop Anti-Ban (Ignore Errors) (RGB)");
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("/C :a");
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("/C reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Epic Games\Unreal Engine\Identifiers" /f");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

but it doesn't let me run `cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("/C reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Epic Games\Unreal Engine\Identifiers" /f");`

No idea why... (another picture to be clear [image: screenshot])

Comment: Hint: \ is an escape character. So \t is interpreted as tab, \r is interpreted as carriage return, \n is interpreted as line feed, \\ is interpreted as literal \, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape `"` in your string like this `\"` and `\` in the path should be also escaped this way `\\`:

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("/C reg delete \"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Epic Games\\Unreal Engine\\Identifiers\\" /f");
```

Comment: Did you try that?  Those backslashes used as separators need to be escaped as well. (like "...USER\Soft..." should be "...USER\\Soft...")

Comment: @Flydog57 you are right, thank you for your comment.

Comment: A deeper problem is that we can't write "/C" *command-line* options to stdin of a single cmd.exe process. Write commands without "/C" that end in `"\r\n"` (CRLF). Set a unique `prompt`. After writing a command, use an inner loop to read lines from stdout until the prompt is read. Otherwise either the stdin or stdout pipe could fill up and block the child process (i.e. cmd.exe for internal commands, or a grandchild process such as reg.exe).